# Bad Practice to use IUnityContainer as Constructor parameter? Alternatives?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, prism

I asked myself if it is a bad practice to use a DI Container in the constructor of an implemented class like this:

```
public LoginViewModel( IUnityContainer unityContainer ) { //... }
```

If so ... what is a good workaround if I have more than 5 params I need to pass? Redesign? When is it 'allowed' to use the Container?

What about the principles in .NET PRISM ? While loading a module I sometimes have to register specific classes inside a Module but this is against the composition root principle isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it is bad practise to inject the container into the viewmodel, simply because, it shouldn't be necessary. This blog post summarises the reasons quite concisely: [MVVM anti-pattern: Injecting the IoC container into a View Model](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/mvvm-anti-pattern-injecting-ioc.html)

The view model itself doesn't decide what classes (interfaces) it needs to use. It has a defined job, it receives its dependencies (defined in the constructor) and works with them.  If it has a lot of dependencies, I would start to think, am I violating the purpose of this view model, that is, is it still SOLID.  I look through all the dependencies and if the work being done is justified, then fine.  If not, then I break it out in an appropriate fashion.

For your modules, in your bootstrapper you register all your modules in one location (for Unity, by overriding the ConfigureModuleCatalog method). Each module will be required to register its own components with the container so it is perfectly valid for the module to receive the container. It is only when the ConfigureModuleCatalog is executed at application startup, that the entire object graph is finally composed. This is what the composition root pattern is all about.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can do this, but than has your LoginViewModel a direct dependency to the Unity container (Framework) and normally you want to avoid this. This also makes it hard to test your LoginViewModel, cause you need to instantiate (or mock) the Container in your tests.

Also if you want to switch your DI Framework you need to change your class.

Best practice for class design and dependency injection is to inject all required dependencies via constructor and optional dependencies via properties. For the optional dependencies your class could set a default implementation in the constructor.

Without further knowledge about your class design it is hard so say if you need to refactor or redesign your class, but it smells that your LoginViewModel has more responsibility than it should have.

I have used PRISM in my last application I worked on and for Modules, that need to register additional types in the container for DI, it is totally fine to pass an instance of the UnityContainer to.